# onClickListener not working in my activity

Tags: android, onclick

My layout has 13 TextViews which on click changes the ListView Items.

Here is my activity:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends ListActivity implements
        OnClickListener {

    private String[] sa = new String[100];
    private ListView lv;
    private Context context = this;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new LongOperation().execute("1");
        lv = getListView();
    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                ExampleActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            int i = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
                if (i != 5 && i != 10) {
                    sa[n] = "Item" + i;
                } else {

                }
            }
            return params[0];
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(context,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sa);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
            this.dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        }
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.d("onClick", v.getId() + "**");
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id) {

        case R.id.tv1: {

            new LongOperation().execute("1");
        }
        case R.id.tv2: {

            new LongOperation().execute("2");
        }
        case R.id.tv3: {

            new LongOperation().execute("3");
        }
        case R.id.tv4: {

            new LongOperation().execute("4");
        }
        case R.id.tv5: {

            new LongOperation().execute("5");
        }
        case R.id.tv6: {

            new LongOperation().execute("6");
        }
        case R.id.tv7: {

            new LongOperation().execute("7");
        }
        case R.id.tv8: {

            new LongOperation().execute("8");
        }
        case R.id.tv9: {

            new LongOperation().execute("9");
        }
        case R.id.tv10: {

            new LongOperation().execute("10");
        }
        case R.id.tv11: {

            new LongOperation().execute("11");
        }
        case R.id.tv12: {

            new LongOperation().execute("12");
        }
        case R.id.tv13: {

            new LongOperation().execute("13");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

the listView is populated as item1 when i launch the app. but when i click on any of the TextViews, the onClick method is not triggered. i checked it using a Log.

Thank You.

Comment: The textviews are populated as a listview.
Try using setOnItemClickListener for this

Comment: the TextViews i have are different from the ListView. They are like tab buttons at the top of the layout, above the ListView

Comment: So the design is like textviews at the top and the below you are having listView.
and now the textView onclicks are not working?
have you used setOnclickListener for TextViews?

Comment: no. but i made the textviews clickable = true in the layout and implemented onClickListener in the activity

Comment: Did you post the code the same code above?

Comment: Just clickable = true doesnt help you in making the items to be recognized to their click events.
you must also set Listeners for them like setOnclickListener(theView);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you are **not registering** `onClickListener` with your `TextViews` hence your TextViews are not getting Clicked event.

For this you have to do something like,

```
onCreate()
{


 TextView tv1 = (TextVIew)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
 tv1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**Better Solution:**

In your Activity's xml Layout File,

in your all `TextView` put attribute `android:onClick="textClick"`

Now remove onClickListener from your Activity and just write

```
public void textClick(View TextView)
```

in your activity. Then you don't have to register onClicklistener for all TextView. Android does itself for you..

Answer (score 3):

This is a sample program provided when you use implements OnClickListener

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedValues) {

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.corky);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);  // have a look on this line. registering.
    }

    // Implement the OnClickListener callback
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

this happens because you not using the `setOnClickListener()` for your `TextViews`

Answer (score 0):

Add this static function in your activity class, This work for me in my **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 static {
  AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

}
```